# UDIDs in provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, code-signing, ios-provisioning, udid, provisioning-profile

Given a provisioning profile, does anyone know how to determine what UDIDs are in that profile?

Comment: @Jasarien - How do I accept answers?  Do I click on the arrow above the number of the answer?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Open it up in a text editor. You should be able to see the list of UDID's.

They appear under the key "Provisioned Devices".

Comment: Look like you figured it out :)

Comment: is it possible to add a UDID manually in the provisioning file in this case?

Comment: Not that I know of. The Device needs to be added to the devices section of the Apple portal as well as in the provisioning profile. Also I think there's a cryptographic hash for the profile that is comprised of the provisioned UDIDs.

Comment: Its encrypted. If you open it in TextEditor

Comment: It's not encrypted - it's a binary PList, so unless the text editor you're using supports binary PList format, it will be shown in the wrong encoding.

Comment: It’s hashed and signed by a CA, if you change it, it will fail  the validation.

Answer (score 65):

To see which iOS device UDID's are associated to your provisioning profile, use the Terminal command:

> security cms -D -i /path/to/MyProfile.mobileprovision

(drag and drop the .mobileprovision file from Finder to the Terminal  window to fill in the file path)

Within the command results look for the ProvisionedDevices section for the device UDIDs associated to the profile, such as:

```
 <key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
<array>
    <string>abab79177cse660edf75b4affe9d87ef2685ade2</string>
    <string>3436dc195c5432f1c22b5a687adfcd350de3af0a</string>
    <string>04589ca69bbde998a72f320s7148290603bc025c</string>
    <string>8a684993a490ebfdf564ef20d5fa38ebfb31b8d7</string>
    <string>16663b95823sf346fc377c3d31a90bc9fcd61d1d</string>
    <string>2e88a9cb3155fc81577c580b86s74351e3f50d5b</string>
    <string>105404f9945627sa24be595015a7cb5655f096f1</string>
    <string>7ea5s4fe4ee0c8d40a18117c446306663fc0bf73</string>
</array>
```

Comment: this answer should be the answer, sometimes opening the profile with text editor show only binaries.

Comment: ... And if there *is* no section called `ProvisionedDevices`, then no devices are included in the profile.

Comment: @Ben, Right. No ProvisionedDevices key indicates a distribution profile (either App Store or In House). However, In House profiles contain the ProvisionsAllDevices key.

Comment: this is the best way of verifying, no need for extra apps, just good old grep

Answer (score 5):

*Sorry for the auto-plug that follows - I'm the author of the mentionned plugin, but felt it was an appropriate answer to this question.*

I wrote a QuickLook plugin just for this need.
It gives you a sorted list of all the UDIDs in the profile. When it knows more about a specific UDID, it will allow you to display a pop-up to get more information about the device.

It is also an easy way to get access to other useful informations about the profile: creation and expiration date, App ID, profile name...

Download it [here](http://www.macmation.com/blog/2011/10/quicklook-plugin-for-mobile-provision-files/).

[image: Screenshot of the plugin]

Comment: Server down for the site.

Comment: it's a pity that you no longer own this website...

Answer (score 3):

Another QuickLook plug-in I use is ProvisionQL.

https://github.com/ealeksandrov/ProvisionQL

It provides the QuickLook feature for provisioning profiles!

[image: provisioning profie example]

Check out more screenshots for how it work: https://github.com/ealeksandrov/ProvisionQL/blob/master/screenshots.md