# How to lead in multi-devices identifer to a new apple developer account?

Tags: ios, user-accounts

In my old apple developer account, I have dozens of device identifiers, you see in the below account.

[image]

Now, I have a anther developer account, I want to put all of the devices identifier to the new developer account.

How to simply do that?

Comment: Since there is no direct way, just select both the columns and copy, open google spreadsheet, paste the copied list, you should get two columns of data. Now interchange the second column ie the Device to first column that is Device Name and add a new first row with Title `Device ID` and next `Device Name`. Now goto `File->Download As->Tab-Separated values` it will create a `.tsv` file, after creation rename the file to `.txt`. Now goto new account device tab you will get option to Register Multiple Device, click that and choose the saved text file, you will get all the device imported.

Comment: Check and find [if this works](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052814/export-devices-added-in-apples-ios-provision-portal) any longer or not.

Comment: @pkc456 I will try.

Answer (score 0):

Create a demo provisioning profile with all the device, download the provisioning run the following command `security cms -D -i /path/to/MyProfile.mobileprovision` ([taken from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9778131/2246798)) you will have the list of the device ids and the device name from there you can easily modify the string containing the values to make the text file or .deviceids plist file for importing.

**EDIT**

Just found another way just drag the cursor to select the name and the id only from the screen, it will look like this one : [image: it will look like this one]

then paste it on a text file(other than textedit, it will create a rtf file), it will have the id and name only so that you can easily import it.

Comment: This will give just the DeviceID, not the Device Name, and its overhead to put all those again.